# How to make anonymous functions with local parameters

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

How do I make this javascript alert 0, 1 and 2 instead of 3 3's?

```
var vals = [1, 2, 3];
for(var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++)
{
    window.setTimeout(function() {alert(i);}, 1000);
}
```

I know the reason why it does this, but I can't figure out, how to pass `i` to the anonymous function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can wrap this in a closure like so:

```
var vals = [1, 2, 3];

for(var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
    (function(num) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {alert(vals[num]);}, 1000);
     })(i);
}
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/qgL7h/

Comment: Nice work.  I did notice that sometimes the numbers were alerted in the order 1, 3, 2.  (maybe one out of 5 times running it in Chrome 13)

Comment: The order doesn't matter, and you shouldn't rely on the order of setTimeout or setInterval anyway

Answer (score 3):

```
var vals = [1, 2, 3];
function makeCallback(i)
{
    return function () {alert(i);};
}
for(var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++)
{
    window.setTimeout(makeCallback(i), 1000);
}
```

Comment: IT will work but not valid syntax as `window.setTimeout` requires a function reference, not a code to execute.

Comment: You don't even need to return a function, it seems -- just fire off `alert(i)` inside makeCallback

Comment: Try it.  makeCallback returns a function reference, so it'll work.

Comment: @Tyilo: `setTimeout` requires a function as its first argument. Calling `makeCallback(i)` returns a function, so it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is not strictly necessary to pass i to the function, it can be assigned to a local var inside.

```
var vals = [1, 2, 3];

for(var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
    (function() {
        var num = i
        window.setTimeout(function() {alert(vals[num]);}, 1000);
     })();
}
```

The "function(){block}()" was required, because Javascript didn't have proper block lexical variables. Recent editions have added "let", which makes this possible:

```
var vals = [1, 2, 3];

for(var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
    let num = i
    window.setTimeout(function() {alert(vals[num]);}, 1000);
}
```